# Как получить данные установщика?

Tags: android

```
Intent intentSetup = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intentSetup.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivityForResult(intentSetup,1);
```

Есть такой код. который устанавливает некое APK приложение.

Как сделать так чтобы в `OnActivityResult`. Я получил результат кнопок. Отмена или установить. А после окна установки, Отмена или Открыть (тут я имею ввиду окно где уже установилось приложение и оно српашивает открыть приложение или закрыть)

Comment: никак. Вам этих данных никто не предоставит. Максимум можно посмотреть список установленных пакетов, и определить, установлен ли нужный.

Comment: @metalurgus, Я использовал в OnActivityResult, И на чтобы я не нажал при возврате в Activity Я получаю RESULT_CANCELED

Comment: как я написал выше,  Вам этих данных никто не предоставит.